# Spiking neural network framework for training simple networks with no biases and negative weights

Tags: neuromorphic-engineering, spiking-neural-networks

I'm looking for a spiking neural network framework to train (at the beginning) a simple network with two or so hidden layers against MNIST digits dataset, and then to take the weights and try to model it as an electrical circuit. That's why I'm looking for a framework that could best describe physical LIF nodes and connections.

An example model of physical LIF (obviously the framework doesn't have to implement this exactly) modeled by differential equation taken from S. R. Nandakumar, et al. (2020). Here $C_m$ is the membrane capacitance, $g_L$ is the leak conductance, $E_L$ is the leak reversal potential, and $I(t)$ is the
net synaptic current fowing into the neuron.

$$C_m\frac{dV(t)}{dt}=-g_l(V(t) - E_L) + I(t) $$

I tried to use NengoDL, but the neurons there have biases (which aren't present in physical description of LIF neurons, and I haven't found a way to disable them), and it would be great if you could restrict the weights to only positive values (as far as I know you can't do this in Nengo).